# Can web application worked both in Tomcat 10 and Tomcat 9

Tags: jakarta-ee, backwards-compatibility, tomcat9

From [tomcat's migration documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/migration-10.html), we know there is a big change from Tomcat 9 to Tomcat 10 which is the specification APIs has changed from javax... to jakarta....

So I using [Tomcat migration tool](https://github.com/apache/tomcat-jakartaee-migration) to change a web application from `javax.*` to `jakarta.*`. And deployed the migrated war into Tomcat 10, it works successfully.

I want to do some changes with the migrated war to ensure it also can be deployed in Tomcat 9. I have tried put Tomcat 10's servlet-api.jar into application's `WEB-INF/lib` but it failed due to some classes cannot be casted to class `javax.servlet.Filter`.

Is there any workaround if want to ensure a web application worked both in Tomcat 10 and Tomcat 9?